# LESS and CSS Imports - Going Crazy

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, import, less

I have an issue currently with my LESS and CSS where an import into Bootstrap.less is being called before an overriding file, yet the first import is overriding the CSS..

As an example, let's say my bootstrap.less file looks like this:

```
/* ALL STANDARD BOOTSTRAP LESS FILE HERE*/

// Generic Widget Styles
@import "components/_widget-styles.less";

// Header Area
@import "components/_header-area.less";

// Global Search Spinner
@import "components/_search-spinner.less";

// Smart Feed
@import "components/_smart-feed.less";

// Home Page Container
@import "components/_home-container.less";

// Footer
@import "components/_footer.less";

// Documents Page Container
@import "components/_documents.less";
```

My Generic Widgets styles have some styles that can be used and overriden all over the site and in the home page container I do just that and it works fine, however for some reason I am having to use !important to override any styles which isn't really a great thing to do imo. Should it use the last style to be added to the CSS file?

Comment: Please, post an abstract of `_widget-styles.less` and `_home-container.less` that cause conflict, so we could be able to understand what is happening.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible to suggest anything by looking just at abstract file names. We need more details (at least): example of some widget code, example of the overriding code and the method of "import into Bootstrap.less".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should it use the last style to be added to the CSS file?

**Only when both selectors have the same specificity.**

If you can override your styles rules only with `!important` the css specificity of your selectors is not high enough. Example:

html:

```
<div class="main"><h1>Test</h1></div>
```

css:

```
.main h1 {color: red;}
h1 {color: blue;}
```

The above will show you the text in red instead of blue due to `.main h1` having a higher specificity than `h1`. Using !import will work, but will be considered as bad practice. Instead of using `!important` you should use selectors with a higher specificity in your Less code for overriding.

For instance the following CSS will solve it (equal specificity):

```
.main h1 {color: red;}
.main h1 {color: blue;}
```

The specificity rules can be found at: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you very much!